# Extract lines containing a pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, bioinformatics

I want to extract all the lines in a file containting these patterns: "#1:" and "tree length for".

Input:

```
#1: nexus0002_Pseudomonas_10M     

 branch          t       N       S   dN/dS      dN      dS  N*dN  S*dS

   6..5      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   6..7      0.013   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0008  0.0114   0.3   2.2
   7..1      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   7..4      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   6..8      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   8..2      0.013   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0008  0.0114   0.3   2.2
   8..3      0.013   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0008  0.0114   0.3   2.2

tree length for dN:       0.0023
tree length for dS:       0.0341

#1: nexus0003_Pseudomonas_10M     

 branch          t       N       S   dN/dS      dN      dS  N*dN  S*dS

   6..5      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   6..7      0.013   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0008  0.0114   0.3   2.2
   7..1      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   7..4      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   6..8      0.000   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0000  0.0000   0.0   0.0
   8..2      0.013   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0008  0.0114   0.3   2.2
   8..3      0.013   390.0   195.0  0.0668  0.0008  0.0114   0.3   2.2

tree length for dN:       0.0111
tree length for dS:       0.0444
```

Output:

```
#1: nexus0002_Pseudomonas_10M     

tree length for dN:       0.0023
tree length for dS:       0.0341

#1: nexus0003_Pseudomonas_10M

tree length for dN:       0.0111
tree length for dS:       0.0444
```

Is there any simple sed solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `grep`

```
grep -E "^#1:|tree length for" infile.txt
```

or `sed`

```
sed -n '/^#1:/p;/^tree length for/p' infile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

From the data that you supplied, it looks as if you'd like to get all lines that starts with a non-blank character:

```
$ grep '^[^[:blank:]]' file.in
#1: nexus0002_Pseudomonas_10M   
tree length for dN:       0.0023
tree length for dS:       0.0341
#1: nexus0003_Pseudomonas_10M   
tree length for dN:       0.0111
tree length for dS:       0.0444
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/^[^[:blank:]]/p' file.in
```

In both `grep` and `sed`, `[[:blank:]]` will match a single space or tab character.  `[^[:blank:]]` with therefore match any single character that is *not* a space or a tab.  Putting `^` in front of that anchors the pattern to the start of the line.